# ImportError: No module named while executing python code in Netbeans

Tags: java, pandas, netbeans, pythoninterpreter

I am trying to call python code in NetBeans
and mentioned the right version of python and set the path too
but still am getting

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Already set path and environment variable.

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile(" absolute path to .py file");
```

and I get this error :

> ImportError: No module named pandas while executing python code in Netbeans

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you check output of below commands?
1) which python 2) python --version 3) which pip

Comment: If that doesn't help, I would suggest you install both the modules using, 1) pip install wheel 2) pip install pandas .........Let me know if this doesn't help

Comment: I have already install

Comment: pip install wheel and pandas.

Comment: python version 2.7 is installed